# Wordpress returns error 500 after update theme

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I trying to upload a project in Wordpress, after I created in my local machine, I started to migration to the main host. So I follow the next steps: 1- Migrate the Database; 2- Paste the code; 3 - Install Theme & Plugins. So when I tryed active the plugin:

[image]

Returns this weird error, its like if some code writed again index.php from my "wp-admin" folder and let them like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

After that, when I reload my page, returns 500 error. I try to modified how my .htaccess get the pages in Admin Config but nothing works.

In left side is how Wordpress write the page and in the right side is how is the correct structure.

[image]

Someone with the same problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it's basically useless for troubleshooting. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Issue:**
Sometimes working environment settings can largely differ with that of your hosts unless you are using a provisioning environment. So issues may arise do to the platforms not being idempotent.

**You can try:**

WP-Migrate.
WP-Migrate helps you migrate your work and tries to keep all settings intact as much as possible including your database. It's like the docker of WordPress - if I can say so.

Go about it like this - Download and install WP-Migrate plugin on your local machine. Package and export your site.

On you main host install a any default theme, then install WP-Migrate plugin, import your site and follow the instructions and hopefully you should be sorted.